# How to pass environment variables to rollup.config.js using rollup's loadConfigFile

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, rollupjs

I'm programmatically loading my rollup config file using rollup's `loadConfigFile` and would like to pass environment variables to the config file. This can be done from the rollup cli using `rollup -c --environment VAR_NAME:VALUE`.

The [docs](https://rollupjs.org/javascript-api/#programmatically-loading-a-config-file) for `loadConfigFile` say its second parameter can be an object of cli options, but passing the environment option as shown below doesn't work.

```
loadConfigFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'rollup.config.js'), {
  environment: "VAR_NAME:VALUE",
});
```

Please help. Thanks.